# Why the object disappeared when listed for two times?

Tags: python-3.x

```
>>> x=zip(range(1,10),range(2,11))
>>> list(x)
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6), (6, 7), (7, 8), (8, 9), (9, 10)]
>>> list(x)
[]
```

`x` is a zip object. It can be listed for only one time: when listed for the second time, the contents disappeared. Why?

Comment: Python version? working okay with 2.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) is an iterator [since Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists). This means, it can only be evaluated once. This decision roots presuambly in the fact that often, one only uses zip to loop over it once (e.g. in `for x, y in zip(xs, ys)`), so that there is no need to create the whole list of items in memory before iteration is possible.

When the list creation (like in Python 2) is needed, one can explicitly create a list as you did:

```
list(zip(xs, ys))
```

In Python 2, similar behaviour can be achieved using:

```
from itertools import izip
x = izip(xs, ys)
# x will behave as in Python 3
```